# Nullable and non-nullable values

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, nullable

I am using flutter and firebase for user authentication.

What I am having trouble with is the following segment of code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthClass {

  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

//Signing in a user
  Future<String> signIn({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password
      );
      return "Welcome!";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        return 'No user found for that email.';
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        return 'Wrong password provided for that user.';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The context from which I am calling the signIn function is right here:

```
import 'package:flutter_client_app/Provider/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_client_app/Screens/home.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  TextEditingController _email = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _password = TextEditingController();

  bool isLoading = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Login"),),

        body: isLoading == false ? Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                  controller: _email,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Email"
                  )
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30,),

              TextFormField(
                  controller: _password,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Password"
                  )
              ),

              FlatButton(     <=============================================================
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  onPressed: () {
                    print (_email.text);
                    print (_password.text);
                    setState(() {
                      isLoading = true;
                    });
                    AuthClass()
                        .signIn(
                          email: _email.text.trim(),
                          password: _password.text.trim())
                        .then((value) {
                      if (value == "Welcome!") {
                        setState(() {
                          isLoading = false;
                        });
                        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                                (route) => false);
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          isLoading = false;
                        });
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(value)));
                      }
                    }); <==============================================================
                  },
                  child: Text("Login to account")),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              // GestureDetector(
              //   onTap: () {
              //     Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              //         context,
              //         MaterialPageRoute(
              //             builder: (context) => RegisterPage()), (route) => false);
              //   },
              //   child: Text("Don't have an account? Register"),
              // ),
              //
              // const SizedBox(
              //   height: 10,
              // ),
              // GestureDetector(
              //   onTap: () {
              //     Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              //         context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResetPage()), (route) => false);
              //   },
              //   child: Text("Forgot Password? reset"),
              //),
            ],
          ),
        ) : Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

The errors that I am getting are as follows:

*29:33: Error: The parameter 'email' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'.*

*29:47: Error: The parameter 'password' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'.*

*29:18: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'String' doesn't allow null.*

I've been successful in printing out the values that are being recorded in the TextFormField, but my problems spawn when the signIn async function is called.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `null-safety` feature. You can disable it by change dart sdk in `pubspec.yaml` to `environment:   sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"` instead of `environment: sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"` or make a your class `null-safety`. Also you should return value for `else` of `if` in `catch` part.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthClass {

  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //Signing in a user with nullable parameters
  Future<String> signIn({String? email, String? password}) async {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email as String,
          password: password as String,
      );
      return "Welcome!";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        return 'No user found for that email.';
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        return 'Wrong password provided for that user.';
      }
      else return "No Clear Error"
    }
  }
  //Signing in a user with default value parameters
  Future<String> signIn({String email = "", String password = ""}) async {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
      );
      return "Welcome!";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        return 'No user found for that email.';
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        return 'Wrong password provided for that user.';
      }
      else return "No Clear Error"
    }
  }
}
```